Gazebo doesn't work after the last update
Today I've performed the update of all the packages on my pc and now I'm unable to load srdfs in Gazebo, also the execution of ign gazebo empty.sdf fails.
The version of Gazebo I'm using is Ignition Gazebo Fortress.
The output that I obtain executing ign gazebo -v 4 empty.sdf is:
[Msg] Ignition Gazebo GUI    v6.16.0
[Dbg] [gz.cc:161] Subscribing to [/gazebo/starting_world].
[Dbg] [gz.cc:163] Waiting for a world to be set from the GUI...
[Dbg] [Gui.cc:253] Waiting for subscribers to [/gazebo/starting_world]...
[Wrn] [Gui.cc:261] Waited for 10s for a subscriber to [/gazebo/starting_world] and got none.
[Dbg] [Application.cc:92] Initializing application.
[GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:555] Create main window
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/StyleDialog.qml:112:3: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/StyleDialog.qml:105:3: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/StyleDialog.qml:98:3: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:qml/Main.qml:102:3: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:27:3: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
[GUI] [Dbg] [PathManager.cc:66] Requesting resource paths through [/gazebo/resource_paths/get]
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] file::/Gazebo/GazeboDrawer.qml:242:3: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
[GUI] [Dbg] [Gui.cc:333] GUI requesting list of world names. The server may be busy downloading resources. Please be patient.
[GUI] [Dbg] [Gui.cc:333] GUI requesting list of world names. The server may be busy downloading resources. Please be patient.
[GUI] [Dbg] [Gui.cc:333] GUI requesting list of world names. The server may be busy downloading resources. Please be patient.
[GUI] [Dbg] [Gui.cc:333] GUI requesting list of world names. The server may be busy downloading resources. Please be patient.
[GUI] [Dbg] [Gui.cc:333] GUI requesting list of world names. The server may be busy downloading resources. Please be patient.

Furthermore, if I try to execute any simulation through ROS2, the result is that the output of the shall reamins stuck on Requesting list of world names.
For example, if I try to execute ros2 launch turtlebot4_ignition_bringup turtlebot4_ignition.launch.py, the shell's output is the following:
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/francesco/.ros/log/2024-06-06-20-26-29-209697-francesco-21704
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
ign_args is deprecated, migrate to gz_args!
[parameter_bridge-2] [INFO] [1717698394.294484811] [clock_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/clock (ignition.msgs.Clock) -> /clock (rosgraph_msgs/msg/Clock)] (Lazy 0)
[robot_state_publisher-3] [WARN] [1717698394.423702980] [kdl_parser]: The root link base_link has an inertia specified in the URDF, but KDL does not support a root link with an inertia.  As a workaround, you can add an extra dummy link to your URDF.
[static_transform_publisher-6] [WARN] [1717698394.223993520] []: Old-style arguments are deprecated; see --help for new-style arguments
[static_transform_publisher-6] [INFO] [1717698394.238157122] [tf_odom_std_dock_link_publisher]: Spinning until stopped - publishing transform
[static_transform_publisher-6] translation: ('0.157000', '0.000000', '0.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-6] rotation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '1.000000', '0.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-6] from 'odom' to 'std_dock_link'
[create-7] [ros_ign_gazebo] is deprecated! Redirecting to use [ros_gz_sim] instead!
[create-7] 
[create-7] [INFO] [1717698394.297774056] [ros_gz_sim]: Requesting list of world names.
[create-8] [ros_ign_gazebo] is deprecated! Redirecting to use [ros_gz_sim] instead!
[create-8] 
[create-8] [INFO] [1717698394.265086452] [ros_gz_sim]: Requesting list of world names.
[parameter_bridge-9] [INFO] [1717698394.345158919] [cmd_vel_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/cmd_vel (ignition.msgs.Twist) -> /cmd_vel (geometry_msgs/msg/Twist)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-9] [INFO] [1717698394.353304089] [cmd_vel_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/model/turtlebot4/cmd_vel (geometry_msgs/msg/Twist) -> /model/turtlebot4/cmd_vel (ignition.msgs.Twist)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-10] [INFO] [1717698394.676904015] [pose_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/model/turtlebot4/pose (ignition.msgs.Pose_V) -> /model/turtlebot4/pose (tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-10] [INFO] [1717698394.680635984] [pose_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/model/standard_dock/pose (ignition.msgs.Pose_V) -> /model/standard_dock/pose (tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-11] [INFO] [1717698394.398369313] [odom_base_tf_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/model/turtlebot4/tf (ignition.msgs.Pose_V) -> /model/turtlebot4/tf (tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-12] [INFO] [1717698394.377697901] [bumper_contact_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/bumper_contact (ignition.msgs.Contacts) -> /bumper_contact (ros_gz_interfaces/msg/Contacts)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-13] [INFO] [1717698394.377770257] [cliff_front_left_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/base_link/sensor/cliff_front_left/scan (ignition.msgs.LaserScan) -> /world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/base_link/sensor/cliff_front_left/scan (sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-14] [INFO] [1717698394.405455060] [cliff_front_right_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/base_link/sensor/cliff_front_right/scan (ignition.msgs.LaserScan) -> /world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/base_link/sensor/cliff_front_right/scan (sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-15] [INFO] [1717698394.472862510] [cliff_side_left_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/base_link/sensor/cliff_side_left/scan (ignition.msgs.LaserScan) -> /world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/base_link/sensor/cliff_side_left/scan (sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-16] [INFO] [1717698394.573945678] [cliff_side_right_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/base_link/sensor/cliff_side_right/scan (ignition.msgs.LaserScan) -> /world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/base_link/sensor/cliff_side_right/scan (sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-17] [INFO] [1717698394.593225992] [ir_intensity_front_center_left_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/ir_intensity_front_center_left/sensor/ir_intensity_front_center_left/scan (ignition.msgs.LaserScan) -> /world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/ir_intensity_front_center_left/sensor/ir_intensity_front_center_left/scan (sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-18] [INFO] [1717698394.937819090] [ir_intensity_front_center_right_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/ir_intensity_front_center_right/sensor/ir_intensity_front_center_right/scan (ignition.msgs.LaserScan) -> /world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/ir_intensity_front_center_right/sensor/ir_intensity_front_center_right/scan (sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-19] [INFO] [1717698394.638245610] [ir_intensity_front_left_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/ir_intensity_front_left/sensor/ir_intensity_front_left/scan (ignition.msgs.LaserScan) -> /world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/ir_intensity_front_left/sensor/ir_intensity_front_left/scan (sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-20] [INFO] [1717698394.910096223] [ir_intensity_front_right_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/ir_intensity_front_right/sensor/ir_intensity_front_right/scan (ignition.msgs.LaserScan) -> /world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/ir_intensity_front_right/sensor/ir_intensity_front_right/scan (sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-21] [INFO] [1717698394.689631401] [ir_intensity_left_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/ir_intensity_left/sensor/ir_intensity_left/scan (ignition.msgs.LaserScan) -> /world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/ir_intensity_left/sensor/ir_intensity_left/scan (sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-22] [INFO] [1717698394.779745368] [ir_intensity_right_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/ir_intensity_right/sensor/ir_intensity_right/scan (ignition.msgs.LaserScan) -> /world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/ir_intensity_right/sensor/ir_intensity_right/scan (sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-23] [INFO] [1717698394.833379489] [ir_intensity_side_left_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/ir_intensity_side_left/sensor/ir_intensity_side_left/scan (ignition.msgs.LaserScan) -> /world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/ir_intensity_side_left/sensor/ir_intensity_side_left/scan (sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-24] [INFO] [1717698394.829446028] [buttons_msg_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/create3_buttons (ignition.msgs.Int32) -> /create3_buttons (std_msgs/msg/Int32)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-25] [INFO] [1717698395.031571997] [hmi_display_msg_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/hmi/display/raw (std_msgs/msg/String) -> /hmi/display/raw (ignition.msgs.StringMsg)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-25] [INFO] [1717698395.034352378] [hmi_display_msg_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/hmi/display/selected (std_msgs/msg/Int32) -> /hmi/display/selected (ignition.msgs.Int32)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-26] [INFO] [1717698395.162887848] [hmi_buttons_msg_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/hmi/buttons (ignition.msgs.Int32) -> /hmi/buttons (std_msgs/msg/Int32)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-27] [INFO] [1717698395.172920827] [hmi_led_msg_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/hmi/led/power (std_msgs/msg/Int32) -> /hmi/led/power (ignition.msgs.Int32)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-27] [INFO] [1717698395.174534161] [hmi_led_msg_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/hmi/led/motors (std_msgs/msg/Int32) -> /hmi/led/motors (ignition.msgs.Int32)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-27] [INFO] [1717698395.175165526] [hmi_led_msg_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/hmi/led/comms (std_msgs/msg/Int32) -> /hmi/led/comms (ignition.msgs.Int32)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-27] [INFO] [1717698395.211868934] [hmi_led_msg_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/hmi/led/wifi (std_msgs/msg/Int32) -> /hmi/led/wifi (ignition.msgs.Int32)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-27] [INFO] [1717698395.213327569] [hmi_led_msg_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/hmi/led/battery (std_msgs/msg/Int32) -> /hmi/led/battery (ignition.msgs.Int32)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-27] [INFO] [1717698395.283022670] [hmi_led_msg_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/hmi/led/user1 (std_msgs/msg/Int32) -> /hmi/led/user1 (ignition.msgs.Int32)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-27] [INFO] [1717698395.294232614] [hmi_led_msg_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/hmi/led/user2 (std_msgs/msg/Int32) -> /hmi/led/user2 (ignition.msgs.Int32)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-28] [INFO] [1717698395.245845599] [lidar_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/rplidar_link/sensor/rplidar/scan (ignition.msgs.LaserScan) -> /world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/rplidar_link/sensor/rplidar/scan (sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-29] [INFO] [1717698395.388815655] [camera_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/oakd_rgb_camera_frame/sensor/rgbd_camera/image (ignition.msgs.Image) -> /world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/oakd_rgb_camera_frame/sensor/rgbd_camera/image (sensor_msgs/msg/Image)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-29] [INFO] [1717698395.391180481] [camera_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/oakd_rgb_camera_frame/sensor/rgbd_camera/depth_image (ignition.msgs.Image) -> /world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/oakd_rgb_camera_frame/sensor/rgbd_camera/depth_image (sensor_msgs/msg/Image)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-29] [INFO] [1717698395.391743331] [camera_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/oakd_rgb_camera_frame/sensor/rgbd_camera/points (ignition.msgs.PointCloudPacked) -> /world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/oakd_rgb_camera_frame/sensor/rgbd_camera/points (sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-29] [INFO] [1717698395.393546214] [camera_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/oakd_rgb_camera_frame/sensor/rgbd_camera/camera_info (ignition.msgs.CameraInfo) -> /world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/oakd_rgb_camera_frame/sensor/rgbd_camera/camera_info (sensor_msgs/msg/CameraInfo)] (Lazy 0)
[turtlebot4_node-30] [INFO] [1717698394.794293237] [turtlebot4_node]: Init Turtlebot4 Node Main
[turtlebot4_node-30] [INFO] [1717698395.082655025] [turtlebot4_node]: Buttons Init
[turtlebot4_node-30] [INFO] [1717698395.164756312] [turtlebot4_node]: Init Display
[turtlebot4_node-30] [INFO] [1717698395.287867559] [turtlebot4_node]: Leds Init
[hazards_vector_publisher-33] [INFO] [1717698395.522223043] [hazards_vector_publisher]: Advertised topic: hazard_detection
[hazards_vector_publisher-33] [INFO] [1717698395.532895279] [hazards_vector_publisher]: Subscription to topic: _internal/bumper/event
[hazards_vector_publisher-33] [INFO] [1717698395.549908685] [hazards_vector_publisher]: Subscription to topic: _internal/cliff_front_left/event
[hazards_vector_publisher-33] [INFO] [1717698395.573441494] [hazards_vector_publisher]: Subscription to topic: _internal/cliff_front_right/event
[hazards_vector_publisher-33] [INFO] [1717698395.660651810] [hazards_vector_publisher]: Subscription to topic: _internal/cliff_side_left/event
[hazards_vector_publisher-33] [INFO] [1717698395.661302731] [hazards_vector_publisher]: Subscription to topic: _internal/cliff_side_right/event
[hazards_vector_publisher-33] [INFO] [1717698395.661879270] [hazards_vector_publisher]: Subscription to topic: _internal/wheel_drop/left_wheel/event
[hazards_vector_publisher-33] [INFO] [1717698395.663476052] [hazards_vector_publisher]: Subscription to topic: _internal/wheel_drop/right_wheel/event
[hazards_vector_publisher-33] [INFO] [1717698395.664985880] [hazards_vector_publisher]: Subscription to topic: _internal/backup_limit
[ir_intensity_vector_publisher-34] [INFO] [1717698395.244138329] [ir_intensity_vector_publisher]: Advertised topic: ir_intensity
[ir_intensity_vector_publisher-34] [INFO] [1717698395.244672614] [ir_intensity_vector_publisher]: Subscription to topic: _internal/ir_intensity_front_center_left
[ir_intensity_vector_publisher-34] [INFO] [1717698395.244987808] [ir_intensity_vector_publisher]: Subscription to topic: _internal/ir_intensity_front_center_right
[ir_intensity_vector_publisher-34] [INFO] [1717698395.245286170] [ir_intensity_vector_publisher]: Subscription to topic: _internal/ir_intensity_front_left
[ir_intensity_vector_publisher-34] [INFO] [1717698395.245554291] [ir_intensity_vector_publisher]: Subscription to topic: _internal/ir_intensity_front_right
[ir_intensity_vector_publisher-34] [INFO] [1717698395.245800411] [ir_intensity_vector_publisher]: Subscription to topic: _internal/ir_intensity_left
[ir_intensity_vector_publisher-34] [INFO] [1717698395.246048557] [ir_intensity_vector_publisher]: Subscription to topic: _internal/ir_intensity_right
[ir_intensity_vector_publisher-34] [INFO] [1717698395.246286157] [ir_intensity_vector_publisher]: Subscription to topic: _internal/ir_intensity_side_left
[motion_control-35] [INFO] [1717698395.477353584] [motion_control]: Enabling REFLEX_BUMP
[motion_control-35] [INFO] [1717698395.486957807] [motion_control]: Enabling REFLEX_CLIFF
[motion_control-35] [INFO] [1717698395.506877797] [motion_control]: Enabling REFLEX_STUCK
[motion_control-35] [INFO] [1717698395.517983259] [motion_control]: Enabling REFLEX_WHEEL_DROP
[wheel_status_publisher-36] [INFO] [1717698395.449860005] [wheel_status_publisher]: Advertised topic: wheel_vels
[wheel_status_publisher-36] [INFO] [1717698395.466412668] [wheel_status_publisher]: Advertised topic: wheel_ticks
[mock_publisher-37] [INFO] [1717698395.701407828] [mock_publisher]: Advertised mocked topic: slip_status
[kidnap_estimator_publisher-39] [INFO] [1717698395.810858540] [kidnap_estimator_publisher]: Advertised topic: kidnap_status
[kidnap_estimator_publisher-39] [INFO] [1717698395.829519082] [kidnap_estimator_publisher]: Subscription to topic: hazard_detection
[static_transform_publisher-44] [WARN] [1717698395.829358098] []: Old-style arguments are deprecated; see --help for new-style arguments
[static_transform_publisher-45] [WARN] [1717698395.883465394] []: Old-style arguments are deprecated; see --help for new-style arguments
[robot_state-38] [INFO] [1717698395.893887878] [robot_state]: Advertised topic: battery_state
[ui_mgr-40] [INFO] [1717698395.986752543] [ui_mgr]: Subscription to topic: cmd_lightring
[static_transform_publisher-45] [INFO] [1717698396.002651631] [camera_stf]: Spinning until stopped - publishing transform
[static_transform_publisher-45] translation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-45] rotation: ('0.499952', '-0.500000', '0.500000', '0.500048')
[static_transform_publisher-45] from 'oakd_rgb_camera_optical_frame' to 'turtlebot4/oakd_rgb_camera_frame/rgbd_camera'
[ui_mgr-40] [INFO] [1717698396.014285931] [ui_mgr]: Subscription to topic: cmd_audio
[robot_state-38] [INFO] [1717698396.096868494] [robot_state]: Subscription to topic: dock_status
[static_transform_publisher-44] [INFO] [1717698396.105510724] [rplidar_stf]: Spinning until stopped - publishing transform
[static_transform_publisher-44] translation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-44] rotation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000', '1.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-44] from 'rplidar_link' to 'turtlebot4/rplidar_link/rplidar'
[robot_state-38] [INFO] [1717698396.155609619] [robot_state]: Advertised topic: stop_status
[turtlebot4_node-30] [INFO] [1717698396.244242532] [turtlebot4_node]: Turtlebot4 standard running.
[robot_state-38] [INFO] [1717698396.520391176] [robot_state]: Subscription to topic: odom
[joint_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1717698397.225131094] [joint_state_publisher]: Waiting for robot_description to be published on the robot_description topic...
[parameter_bridge-27] [INFO] [1717698397.970613830] [hmi_led_msg_bridge]: Passing message from ROS std_msgs/msg/Int32 to Gazebo gz.msgs.Int32 (showing msg only once per type)
[parameter_bridge-25] [INFO] [1717698398.245154728] [hmi_display_msg_bridge]: Passing message from ROS std_msgs/msg/String to Gazebo gz.msgs.StringMsg (showing msg only once per type)
[parameter_bridge-25] [INFO] [1717698398.245273458] [hmi_display_msg_bridge]: Passing message from ROS std_msgs/msg/Int32 to Gazebo gz.msgs.Int32 (showing msg only once per type)
[create-8] [INFO] [1717698399.267623785] [ros_gz_sim]: Requesting list of world names.
[create-7] [INFO] [1717698399.298275027] [ros_gz_sim]: Requesting list of world names.
[spawner-32] [INFO] [1717698400.039903851] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-32] [INFO] [1717698402.055626590] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-32] [INFO] [1717698404.071552915] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[create-8] [INFO] [1717698404.267960489] [ros_gz_sim]: Requesting list of world names.
[create-7] [INFO] [1717698404.298543287] [ros_gz_sim]: Requesting list of world names.
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Wrn] [Gui.cc:261] Waited for 10s for a subscriber to [/gazebo/starting_world] and got none.
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/StyleDialog.qml:112:3: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/StyleDialog.qml:105:3: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/StyleDialog.qml:98:3: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:qml/Main.qml:102:3: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:27:3: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] file::/Gazebo/GazeboDrawer.qml:242:3: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
[spawner-32] [INFO] [1717698406.086296129] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-32] [ERROR] [1717698407.899293871] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Controller manager not available
[ERROR] [spawner-32]: process has died [pid 22123, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner joint_state_broadcaster -c controller_manager --ros-args -r __ns:=/'].
[INFO] [spawner-46]: process started with pid [22429]
    [create-8] [INFO] [1717698409.268343498] [ros_gz_sim]: Requesting list of world names.
    [create-7] [INFO] [1717698409.299123109] [ros_gz_sim]: Requesting list of world names.
    [spawner-46] [INFO] [1717698410.556121135] [spawner_diffdrive_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
    [spawner-46] [INFO] [1717698412.569554546] [spawner_diffdrive_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
    [create-8] [INFO] [1717698414.268721199] [ros_gz_sim]: Requesting list of world names.
    [create-7] [INFO] [1717698414.299647825] [ros_gz_sim]: Requesting list of world names.
    [spawner-46] [INFO] [1717698414.585331620] [spawner_diffdrive_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
    [spawner-46] [INFO] [1717698416.600576714] [spawner_diffdrive_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist


Could you please run it with ign --verbose gazebo empty.sdf and add the output here? Also check the logs under $HOME/.gz/ to see if there is a hint about the failure.

@JoseLuisRivero I've executed ign gazebo -v 4 empty.sdf and the output has been added to the post.
The log directory doesn't contain any log about the gazebo's execution since the problem has shown up.

This looks like the server does not start up. What happens when you add -s to your commandline?
